# How i can convert this toggle Aura into LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, javascript, css, lwc-dom

[image]I am not able to convert Controller in LWC JS
below is my code to show toggle or helptext
Aura Component

```
<aura:component >
<div class="slds-form-element">
   <div class="slds-form-element__icon slds-align-middle" onmouseover="{!c.display}" onmouseout="{!c.displayOut}">
      <button class="slds-button slds-button slds-button--icon" aria-describedby="help" title="Help" >


         <lightning:icon iconName="utility:info" size="xx-small" alternativeText="Help"/>
         <span class="slds-assistive-text">Help</span>
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="slds-popover slds-popover--tooltip slds-nubbin--left-top toggle" role="tooltip" id="help" style="position:absolute;top:-4px;left:20px;" aura:id="tooltip">
   <div class="slds-popover__body">This can be utilized to run the the info</div>
</div>  
</aura:component>
```

controller.js

```
({
  display : function(component, event, helper) {
       var toggleText = component.find("tooltip");
      console.log(toggleText);
    $A.util.toggleClass(toggleText, "toggle");
     
  },

  displayOut : function(component, event, helper) {
    var toggleText = component.find("tooltip");
      console.log(toggleText);
    $A.util.toggleClass(toggleText, "toggle");
     
  }
})
```

css

```
/*toggleCss.css*/
 .THIS.toggle {
   display: none;
 }
```

LWC COmponent

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <div class="slds-form-element__icon slds-align-middle" onmouseover={display} onmouseout={displayOut}>
        
              <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:info" size="xx-small" alternative-text="Help"></lightning-icon>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="slds-popover slds-popover--tooltip slds-nubbin--left-top toggle" role="tooltip" id="help" style="position:absolute;top:-4px;left:20px;" data-id="tooltip">
        <div class="slds-popover__body">This can be utilized to run the info</div>
     </div>   
</template>
```

js

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class TestToolip extends LightningElement {
    display(event) {
        var divblock = this.template.querySelector(`[data-id="tooltip"]`);
        console.log("here"+divblock);
        if(divblock){
            this.template.querySelector('[data-id="divblock"]').className='toggle';
        }
    }
    displayOut(event) {
        var divblock = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="tooltip"]');
        if(divblock){
            this.template.querySelector('[data-id="divblock"]').className='toggle';
        }
    }
}
```

css

```
/*toggleCss.css*/
.THIS.toggle {
    display: none;
  }
```

I am facing difficulty in lwc js and not able to get the exact result as aura comp.please suggest

```
<template>
   <lightning-combobox 
                                name="Name"
                                label=" Name"
                                placeholder = "Please select Name"
                                options = ""
                                value = ""
                                >
                            </lightning-combobox>
   <div class="slds-form-element">
     <div class="slds-form-element__icon slds-align-middle" onmouseover={display} onmouseout={displayOut}>
     
           <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:info" size="xx-small" alternative-text="Help"></lightning-icon>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slds-popover slds-popover--tooltip slds-nubbin--left-top toggle" role="tooltip" id="help"  data-id="tooltip">
     <div class="slds-popover__body">This can be utilized to run the info</div>
  </div>   
 </template>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In css file for LWC we do NOT `.THIS`.
Also for this you can use the standard element `classList` property for it (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)).

You must use **the same name for css file which you have for your component** :
[image]

I have updated your code  :

HTML :

```
<template>
  <div class="slds-form-element">
    <div class="slds-form-element__icon slds-align-middle" onmouseover={display} onmouseout={displayOut}>
    
          <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:info" size="xx-small" alternative-text="Help"></lightning-icon>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="slds-popover slds-popover--tooltip slds-nubbin--left-top toggle" role="tooltip" id="help" style="position:absolute;top:-4px;left:20px;" data-id="tooltip">
    <div class="slds-popover__body">This can be utilized to run the info</div>
 </div>   
</template>
```

JS :

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class TestToolip extends LightningElement {

display(event) {
    var divblock = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="tooltip"]');
    console.log("here"+divblock);
    if(divblock){
        divblock.classList.toggle('toggle');
    } 
}

displayOut(event) {
    var divblock = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="tooltip"]');
    console.log("here"+divblock);
    if(divblock){
        divblock.classList.toggle('toggle');
    } 
 }
}
```

CSS :

```
.toggle {
  display: none;
}
```

It is really hard to override `lightning-combobox` styles so for Combobox variant I would use Lighting Design System and [this](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/combobox/)
So HTML would look like this :

```
<template>
<div class="slds-form-element">
  <div style="display: flex;">
<label class="slds-form-element__label" for="combobox-id-59" id="combobox-label-id-138">Relate To</label> 
     <div class="slds-form-element">
        <div class="slds-form-element__icon slds-align-middle" onmouseover={display} onmouseout={displayOut}>
  
           <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:info" size="xx-small" alternative-text="Help"></lightning-icon>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="slds-popover slds-popover--tooltip slds-nubbin--left-top toggle" role="tooltip" id="help"
        style="position:absolute;top:-4px;left:20px;" data-id="tooltip">
        <div class="slds-popover__body">This can be utilized to run the info</div>
     </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="slds-form-element__control">
     <div class="slds-combobox_container">
        <div class="slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click">
           <div class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right" role="none">
              <button type="button" class="slds-input_faux slds-combobox__input"
                 aria-labelledby="combobox-label-id-138 combobox-id-59-selected-value"
                 id="combobox-id-59-selected-value" aria-controls="listbox-id-1" aria-expanded="false"
                 aria-haspopup="listbox">
                 <span class="slds-truncate" id="combobox-value-id-103">Select an Option…</span>
              </button>
              <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-down slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right">
                 <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-icon-text-default" aria-hidden="true">
                    <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#down"></use>
                 </svg>
              </span>
           </div>
           <div id="listbox-id-1" class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_length-5 slds-dropdown_fluid" role="listbox">
              <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="presentation">
                 <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                    <div id="option1"
                       class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small"
                       role="option">
                       <span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon"></span>
                       <span class="slds-media__body">
                          <span class="slds-truncate" title="Accounts">Accounts</span>
                       </span>
                    </div>
                 </li>
                 <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                    <div id="option2"
                       class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small"
                       role="option">
                       <span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon"></span>
                       <span class="slds-media__body">
                          <span class="slds-truncate" title="Reports">Reports</span>
                       </span>
                    </div>
                 </li>
                 <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                    <div id="option3"
                       class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small"
                       role="option">
                       <span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon"></span>
                       <span class="slds-media__body">
                          <span class="slds-truncate" title="Contacts">Contacts</span>
                       </span>
                    </div>
                 </li>
                 <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                    <div id="option4"
                       class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small"
                       role="option">
                       <span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon"></span>
                       <span class="slds-media__body">
                          <span class="slds-truncate" title="Files">Files</span>
                       </span>
                    </div>
                 </li>
                 <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                    <div id="option5"
                       class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small"
                       role="option">
                       <span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon"></span>
                       <span class="slds-media__body">
                          <span class="slds-truncate" title="Groups">Groups</span>
                       </span>
                    </div>
                 </li>
                 <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                    <div id="option6"
                       class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small"
                       role="option">
                       <span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon"></span>
                       <span class="slds-media__body">
                          <span class="slds-truncate" title="Leads">Leads</span>
                       </span>
                    </div>
                 </li>
                 <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                    <div id="option7"
                       class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small"
                       role="option">
                       <span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon"></span>
                       <span class="slds-media__body">
                          <span class="slds-truncate" title="Notes">Notes</span>
                       </span>
                    </div>
                 </li>
                 <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                    <div id="option8"
                       class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small"
                       role="option">
                       <span class="slds-media__figure slds-listbox__option-icon"></span>
                       <span class="slds-media__body">
                          <span class="slds-truncate" title="Groups">Groups</span>
                       </span>
                    </div>
                 </li>
              </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Awesome .perfect .One thing i just want to knwo ..i want to show this tooltip for combobox but when i am doing it tis not showing near to field name its going below combobox

Comment: I have attached the code and result coming. I want right hand side of Field Name. Can you please suggest

Comment: also as per above attached image once i hover to icon combo box is going bit down. .instead of changing combobox place ..how i can show that tooltip popup

Comment: @santu It is really hard to override "lightning-combobox" styles so for Combobox variant I would use Lighting Design System,
I have updated the answer.